# Customizing colormap for Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, manual, color-mapping

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I am trying to find good resources on how to customize a colormap (without using colormap editor) to set your colors and your boundaries for an image in Matlab. I have managed to do it using the colormap editor but I want to figure out how to do it manually.

I am trying to make a colormap that ranges between 0 and 127. The boundaries would be:

0 to 64 is black (0) to white (64)

65 to 127 is blue (65) to red (127)

Can someone give me some advice on how to manually make these changes to the colormap? A good resource would also be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `linspace`. It helps you creating a uniform distribution of numbers in some range.

```
 blackToWhite = repmat(linspace(0,1,66),3,1)' ; 
 l1 = linspace(0,1,127-65+1);
 blueToRed = [flipud(l1(:)) zeros(size(l1(:))) l1(:) ];

 cmap = [blackToWhite; blueToRed];
```

The idea is to interpolate `[1 0 0]` up to `[0 0 1]`; Each of the color channels, red green and blue is interpolated on its own.

```
     Red -> 1 ... 0
     Green -> 0 ... 0
     Blue ->  0 ... 1
```

So I generated `l1` both for the red and the blue channel, but flipped it in one of them.

Comment: How does using linspace determine the colour boundaries?

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @gtdevel, you can upvote the answer in case it was helpful to you. Thanks